# Можно ли как то в Joomla проверять что пользователь еще находится на сайте

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

Можно ли как то в Joomla проверять что пользователь еще находится на сайте? Например написать js скрипт какой нить, чтобы через каждуюу минуту проверял открито ли окно у человека или нет?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду зарегистрированных пользователей?

Comment: @Maqsood, да, но это не очень важно, то я на php проверю, скрипт придумать бы чтобы проверял активность или как то так?

Comment: Ну тут PHP задействовать нужно это - однозначно. По крайне мере я пока такой вариант реализации вижу. Нужно обращаться к таблице сеанса пользователя по `userid`.

Comment: ну это понятно, но сначала нужно узнать покинул ли этот пользователь сайт

Comment: Давненько я с joomla не работал. Но пару лет назад, решил такую задачу именно таким способом. Обращаясь к таблице сессии пользователя, Вы либо находите сессию либо нет. Из этого и вывод, онлайн ли пользователь. Но замечал тут и Вашу активность - Вы, возможно, и на этот свой вопрос найдете решения :D  вы на все свои вопросы отвечаете сами ))))

Comment: Просто я часто метку `joomla` посещаю)))

Comment: @Maqsood, ответ уже нашел :) Написал ниже, может кому понадобится.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена, может куму понадобится вот JS код который проверяет активен ли пользователь

```
<script>
function logout() {
    alert('Тут php и разрушаем сесию');
}
var is_focus = 1;
window.onfocus = function()
{
    is_focus = 1;
}

window.onblur = function()
{
    is_focus = 0;
}

setInterval(function(){
   if(is_focus != 1) logout();
}, 5000);
</script>
```

далее настраиваем время жизни сесии в самой Joomla, таким образом если у человека открыто окно и он что то там себе делает, например просто учит стихотворение то он еще будет активен, но если он ушел на другой сайт а наша вкладка осталась открыта, то через 5 сикунд сессия разрушиться.

Почему так делал? Есть люди у которых вкладки сутками открыты. А потом кто-то садится за их компьютер и начинает наводить там свои порядки.

Comment: В Joomla есть стандартное средство поддержания сессии и сделано оно на JS, так что не городите костылей а учите документацию. Называется это средство `keepalive` и находиться оно в `JHtmlBehavior`